# intel xdk: my links are not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, intel

I am 4 days old using intel xdk application.
 and the software is some how rigid.

I got his errors from the editor which prevent my links from working, but i don't know why as all data are actually in place.

some links are buttons, others are div boxes.
my links are for internal page navigation. 
are the links selected based on ID or css class?

Simply put how do i create navigation # links to link pages?l
I will appreciate a walk around idea.
thanks.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem some times, the first thing I need to know is: is the app running properly in emulator?

JSHint has some bugs and sometimes doesn't detect some information stored in other js files.

Comment: I got the solution. I restarted my system, remove all my IDs and  then retyped them , it worked! the XDK is obviously still in development stage. But i Like it.